# How to get values of array 1 and array 2 based on array index of array3 in laravel/php?

Tags: php, laravel

```
Array1=Array ( [0] => 678 [1] => 137 [2] => 137 [3] => 128 [4] => 137 [5] => 137 [6] => 100 [7] => 137 [8] => 137 [9] => 137 )
Array2=Array ( [0] => 678 [1] => 137 [2] => 137 [3] => 128 [4] => 137 [5] => 137 [6] => 344 [7] => 137 [8] => 137 [9] => 137 )
Array3=Array ( [0] => 20 [3] => 30 [6] => 40 )
```

I have 3 arrays (Array1, Array2, Array3) each having fixed index from 0 to 9 but Array3 index will change based on Array1 and Array2 value. In the above array example, Array3 has 3 index values i.e. ( [0] => 20 [3] => 30 [6] => 40 ). How to get value from array1 and array3 based on index of array3, with the top example, I want Array1 and Array2 of [0], [3], [6] values.
I tried using array_filter and I am able to get only Array3 value but not Array1 and Array2 value.

```
$NewArray1 = array_filter(Array1);
$NewArray2 = array_filter($Array2);
$NewArray3 = array_filter($Array3);
```

Comment: Try [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Comment: foreach($array3 as $key => $value)